# Why can't I append to a slice that's the property of a struct in golang?

Tags: go, struct, append, slice

I'm trying to append a value to a golang slice, the code works if it's called in the first method, but if this method calls another method, the code seems to fail.

Examples (Test3 is what I was originally trying to do):

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

// This works

type Test1 struct {
  all []int
}

func (c Test1) run() []int {
  for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    c.all = append(c.all, i)
  }
  return c.all
}

// This works

var gloabl_all []int

type Test2 struct {}

func (c Test2) run() []int {
  c.combo()
  return gloabl_all
}

func (c Test2) combo() {
  for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    gloabl_all = append(gloabl_all, i)
  }
}

// This doesn't

type Test3 struct {
  all []int
}

func (c Test3) run() []int {
  c.combo()
  return c.all
}

func (c Test3) combo() {
  for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    c.all = append(c.all, i)
    fmt.Println("Test3 step", i + 1, c.all)
  }
}

func main() {
  test1 := &Test1{}
  fmt.Println("Test1 final:", test1.run(), "\n")

  test2 := &Test2{}
  fmt.Println("Test2 final:", test2.run(), "\n")

  test3 := &Test3{}
  fmt.Println("Test3 final:", test3.run())
}
```

This outputs:

```
Test1 final: [0 1] 

Test2 final: [0 1] 

Test3 step 1 [0]
Test3 step 2 [0 1]
Test3 final: []
```

Playground copy: https://play.golang.org/p/upEXINUvNu

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Must use pointer receiver or else you append to a copy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything in Go is passed by value. And a copy is made of the passed value.

`Test3.combo()` has value (non-pointer) receiver:

```
func (c Test3) run() []int {
  c.combo()
  return c.all
}

func (c Test3) combo() {
  for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    c.all = append(c.all, i)
    fmt.Println("Test3 step", i + 1, c.all)
  }
}
```

This means when `Test3.combo()` is called from `Test3.run()` like `c.combo()`, a copy is made of `c` (which is of type `Test3`). The `combo()` method operates on a copy. It properly appends 2 numbers to `Test3.all`, but when this method returns, the copy is discarded.

So when `Test3.run()` returns `c.all`, it returns an empty (`nil`) slice, because the slice to which `Test3.combo()` appended, was a field of a copy, and which has been discarded.

Solution: simply use a pointer receiver:

```
func (c *Test3) combo() {
  for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    c.all = append(c.all, i)
    fmt.Println("Test3 step", i + 1, c.all)
  }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JjUurm2eqy)):

```
Test1 final: [0 1] 

Test2 final: [0 1] 

Test3 step 1 [0]
Test3 step 2 [0 1]
Test3 final: [0 1]
```

Note the star `*` in the receiver: `func (c *Test3) combo()`. By adding it, you make the receiver a pointer, and so when `combo()` is called, it only receives a pointer to a value of type `Test3`, and it will modify the pointed value, the value that `Test3.run()` has, so when `combo()` returns, the changes are not lost.

Comment: That was easy! Makes sense, thanks for your help (this was also useful: https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/08/09/dont-get-bitten-by-pointer-vs-non-pointer-method-receivers-in-golang/)